# How to escape a value returned from a command that contains special symbol in the shell script

Tags: bash, printf, escaping

I'm working on the shell script that creates a file with .env extension that contains environment variables that I'm getting from azure key vault.
The problem is that when I'm fetching a password it contains a special character "%" that is being interpreted as an unknown command with the following message:
%N: invalid directive

The file looks like:

```
#!/bin/zsh

touch vars.env 

printf "PASSWORD=$(az keyvault secret show --name app-PASSWORD --vault-name "my-vault" --query "value";) \n" >>vars.env
```

and the result in the file (only the part before "%" symbol):

`PASSWORD="bKt39f`

The question is how to escape it so the whole password would be written in the file instead of a part of it.

Comment: In the words of [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net): "Don't use variables in the printf format string. Use printf '..%s..' "$foo"." ([more info](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2059))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `printf` wrong. Its first argument is a format string, which tells it how to print the actual data (which is in the rest of the arguments). In the format string, `%` indicates a format specifier, which tells it to insert one of the data arguments (and the stuff immediately after `%` tells it how to format that data). Use something like this:

```
printf 'PASSWORD=%s\n' "$(az keyvault secret show --name app-PASSWORD --vault-name "my-vault" --query "value";)" >>vars.env
```

or maybe treat the "PASSWORD=" as data rather than part of the format:

```
printf '%s\n' "PASSWORD=$(az keyvault secret show --name app-PASSWORD --vault-name "my-vault" --query "value";)" >>vars.env
```

In both of these, the `%s` in the format string means "insert the next piece of data as a plain string".

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my question was wrong. I've used "echo" instead of "printf" and the problem was solved. But your answer helped me to recognise the problem.

Comment: @MaksymFedosov Actually, I'd recommend one of the corrected `printf` versions instead of `echo`, because while `echo` won't do anything weird with `%`, it *might* do weird things with ```\```. Or it might not. It's weird and inconsistent, and therefore best to avoid it. When you use it correctly, `printf` *just works*. See the Unix & Linux question ["Why is printf better than echo?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)